# How to loop through an IP range?

Tags: python, ip

What's the easiest way to loop through an IP range in python? I saw a couple of examples but none of them worked for me. I tried the following technique, works perfectly, but it will not exit the loop when it reaches the end of the range. For example, I will specify the following arguments via the command line

```
python loop.py 1.0.0.0 2.0.0.0
```

and the loop will not stop execution when the range reaches 2.0.0.0

```
start_ip = string.split(sys.argv[1], ".")
end_ip = string.split(sys.argv[2], ".")

for c1 in range(int(start_ip[0]), 255):
    for c2 in range(int(start_ip[1]), 255):
        for c3 in range(int(start_ip[2]), 255):
            for c4 in range(int(start_ip[3]), 255):
                if "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (c1, c2, c3, c4) == "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (int(end_ip[0]), int(end_ip[1]), int(end_ip[2]), int(end_ip[3])):
                    break
                else:
                    print "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (c1, c2, c3, c4)
```

It would be great if someone could tell me why my code isn't working correctly, or show me a better way to iterate through an IP range, thanks. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Using the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress.html) would be by far the easiest, but it includes this functionality only from version 3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looping logic is wrong. At the `if` statement where you do the comparison with the upper bound of the IP address, the `break` statement only breaks the immediate loop above the `if` statement.

Therefore it continues to run for the whole range. You need to break from each of the for loops. Something like this :

```
done = False

for c1 in range(int(start_ip[0]), 255):
    for c2 in range(int(start_ip[1]), 255):
        for c3 in range(int(start_ip[2]), 255):
            for c4 in range(int(start_ip[3]), 255):
                if "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (c1, c2, c3, c4) == "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (int(end_ip[0]), int(end_ip[1]), int(end_ip[2]), int(end_ip[3])):
                    done = True
                    break
                else:
                    print "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (c1, c2, c3, c4)
            if(done):
                break
        if(done):
            break
    if(done):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

As an IP is just 4 bytes, it can be expressed as a single 32-bit integer. That way, if we can transform from and to this integer, we only need one loop:

```
# How much is each byte 'worth' in the ip?
units = [1 << (8 * i) for i in range(3, -1, -1)]


def ip_to_int(ip):
    return sum(int(byte) * unit for (byte, unit) in zip(ip.split('.'), units))


def int_to_ip(i):
    return '.'.join(str((i / bit) & 0xff) for bit in units)

#----------------------
start_ip = "1.0.0.0"
end_ip = "2.0.0.0"

ips = (int_to_ip(i) for i in xrange(ip_to_int(start_ip), ip_to_int(end_ip)))
for ip in ips:
    print ip
```

This makes the looping really easy, and also gives you easy ways to see if one IP is bigger than another or equal to it (just compare the ints).